# Unknown Field In Where Clause

Tags: mysql

I received a database containing Table Permanent with Two Columns `Quota_our` and `Quota_theirs` For each row I have If one is not empty  the other column is empty and I need to have one column to work with so I tried to Update One of these Columns and once the records are swapped I will delete the other table.
 The thing is I am not really into MySql but I need this database for a side project I tried Nesting Selects as you couldn't set an update getting a value from a select within the same table so I tried this :

```
UPDATE permanent
SET Quota_our = (
    SELECT q
    FROM (
        SELECT Quota_theirs AS q, CT_NUM AS code_x
        FROM permanent
        WHERE Quota_our = 0 OR Quota_our IS NULL
    )
) AS A
WHERE
    A.code_x = permanent.CT_NUM AND
    permanent.CT_NUM IS NOT NULL
```

But I get this Error :

> Unknown field 'A.code_x' in where clause
>   I have searched quite well for any related questions , all of whom couldn't get me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks like you should use join instead of subquery

Comment: I've seen people using about join but i couldn't figure it out , if you could pull an example  it would be appreciated

Comment: This approach won't work because you can only select a single value `Quota_theirs` from the inner table, so `CT_NUM` won't be available in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I understand that  the logic of this approach is weird , but is there any way the inner table could be available with both of it's columns as I  need to respect these condition for this to work perfectly?

Comment: Checkout the answers below, and maybe rewrite your query using a join instead of the subquery.  By the way, I couldn't figure out your logic, please include more sample data next time.

Comment: @KhaledOuertani nope, that's not possible, see my answer below

Comment: I like the answer you posted @Shadow but In my post , I specified that in order for the Update to be set , `CT_NUM` Must never be Null as it is not Nullable and therefore could not be counted on as unique Identifier unless it's not Null

Comment: @KhaledOuertani none of the suggested answers change the value of ct_num, so, I do not really understand the point.

Comment: @chiragsatapara sqlfiddle keeps reponding with a  Gateway Time-Out And I don't know if it's appropiate to just put the sql script in here. Shadow 's Answer made the trick for me and Tim Beigeleisen' s advise put me on the right course , all I had to do was use join for the column to known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree, the error message is a bit misleading here. Actually, it should say `unknown table A` and the root cause would be more clear.

The problem is that `code_x` field is defined in the derived table `A` that is created while you assign value to the `Quota_our` field. However, in order to reference a field (well, table) in the `where` clause, the table must be listed in the `table_reference` section of the [update statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

You can get around this issue by using a multi-table `update` statement avoiding the need for the subquery:

```
UPDATE permanent as p1 
INNER JOIN permanent as p2 on p2.CT_NUM = p1.CT_NUM
SET p1.`Quota_our` = p2.`Quota_theirs`
WHERE p1.CT_NUM IS NOT NULL AND (p2.Quota_our= 0 OR p2.`Quota_our` IS NULL)
```

Comment: Sorry Shadow I am  a beginner with mysql and databases but this worked , I only had the reference.